# mplayer not sending the correct user-agent

Tags: ffmpeg, http, mplayer, streaming

I am trying to play a stream through mplayer. Here is the command I execute:

```
mplayer -user-agent "PS4 libhttp/1.60" -cache 8192 -v ffmpeg://http://the_stream_url.m3u8
```

The stream does not play due to a `403 - Forbidden error`. This is expected if the user-agent is not correctly set. What makes me think the user-agent is not read correctly is that every HTTP request shows this user-agent instead:

```
User-Agent: Lavf/55.33.100
```

Is there anything I did not understand or do correctly?

Also note that I can correctly play the stream through VLC by using the same URL and `:http-user-agent=PS4 libhttp/1.60` as the edit options.

[Here is the full log, if needed.](http://pastebin.com/9pQYQf9c)

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in mplayer; if you omit ffmpeg:// prefix, custom user-agent is actually sent.  Passing `-lavfdopts o=user-agent=whatever` also does not work.

Comment: Did that actually get fixed at some point?